# Using a hard drive duplicator with Ubuntu

Tags: cloning

I am using an Aleratec Copy Cruiser and I am trying to copy an unencrypted Ubuntu image, but when I boot the copied drives it will load GRUB and then restart no matter which option I pick.

I am trying the copied drives on both new computers, and the same computer the image was built on. Both computers are exactly the same.

Does anyone know what might cause that?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: Are you trying to boot them on the machine that created them?  Does the original boot? Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Comment: Thy don't you use one of the built-in tools like `dd` to copy file system images?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get a response from Aleratec, and they told me to enable copying HPA which is not set by default. Once I did that the copies worked, although the image still took much longer than what I am used to to copy.